# Where does Ubuntu 18.04 stores network settings?

Tags: network-manager

I have two virtual Ubuntu systems, set network settings via graphical interface on one system and decided to enter them manualy in the second one, but  [known to me config files seem empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8nBU.png). Where can I find the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise, connections you created via graphical interface are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, for example on my working PC I have file `Wired connection 1.nmconnection` in this directory with such content for static IP connection:

```
[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=a3e912b0-f428-333f-a097-3a82d768a3cd
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-100
permissions=

[ethernet]
duplex=half
mac-address=78:24:AF:3D:CD:21
mac-address-blacklist=
speed=100

[ipv4]
address1=192.168.1.8/21
dns-search=
method=manual

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
dns-search=
method=auto
```

and `Wired connection 2.nmconnection` for DHCP connection, which differs in `[ipv4]` section:

```
[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

Note, in this file there is device uuid instead of network card name. To match uuid's and card name you can use `nmcli connection show`:

```
NAME                    UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1      a3e912b0-f428-333f-a097-3a82d768a3cd  ethernet  eno1
```

Comment: This file is empty on Ubuntu 20.04.x. I was not able to find information on /etc/netplan nor /etc/network folders ...

Answer (score 0):

It is in `/etc/NetworkManager` directory